# Clicking button in Vaadin application has no effect with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, vaadin, vaadin8

I'd like to interact with a Vaadin application (Vaadin 8) using WebDriver. The login form is wrapped using the `PageObject` pattern.

```
@Test
public void login() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/intern/login");

    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.enterUserCredentials("test", "test");
    loginPage.submit();
}
```

The `submit()` method finds the login button and triggers a `.click()`.

```
@FindBy(id = "loginButton")
private WebElement loginButton;

public void submit() {
  this.loginButton.click();
}
```

When using the "real" application the click triggers several requests and responses to/from the server until the next page after the login page is loaded.

In the above WebDriver example however nothing happens after the click although I instructed the driver to do an implicit wait.

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: What does `submit()` look like?

Comment: @Morfic Updated my question and added the code.

Comment: That looks fine. Could your login page have some sort of checks on the length/structure/complexity of the username and password? As in, are you sure that "test"/"test" are valid credentials and the button is enabled to be clickable?

Comment: Yes, the credentials are valid. When using the developer tools of the browser I can see that after clicking the button several XHR requests/responses are exchanged with the server. Maybe I need to handle this in any way.

Comment: That's probably the Vaadin framework _communication channel_, so I doubt you have to do something yourself. I wanted to ask for a [sscce](http://sscce.org) but you profile says you're a test engineer so you probably don't have access to the app sources. Is there any way you could get one of your dev colleagues to assist you in debugging this problem or help you create a sample app to reproduce the issue? If you did not see any errors or suspicious messages in the developer tools console and without a way to reproduce it, I'm out of ideas for the time being...

Comment: try with Thread.sleep before submit. you can also try click by using javascript executor